# Given the current market situation, should I put all my money in bonds?

Tags: investing

I don't know much about finance, but I do know that:

1. to combat inflation, the federal reserve is raising interest rates, which means the fixed rate I receive on a bond like a treasury note also goes up, and therefore becomes a better investment
2. the rising interest rates will lead to a recession or slowdown of the economy, thus making stocks less likely to give a good return

So in summary, should I invest heavily in bonds now, and remove most/all of my holdings in stocks? And then when the market seems like it's going back up, I can then invest in stocks?

Note that whenever I say "bonds" or "stocks", I'm always talking about index funds. I never pick individual bonds or individual stocks, I'm too dumb for that.

Comment: Rising interest rates hurts bonds too.

Answer (score 6):

> So in summary, should I invest heavily in bonds now, and remove
> most/all of my holdings in stocks? And then when the market seems like
> it's going back up, I can then invest in stocks?

what you are trying to do is time the market. You see that investment type X has been dropping, but investment type Y is going up. So you are wanting to switch from a stock heavy max to a bond heavy mix. Then switch when things look different.

Timing the market works best if you guess right both times. Too bad you know the peak/bottom only after it has passed.

Don't make big moves based on what everybody else is doing.

You should pick a mix based on your age, goals, and risk tolerance. Then don't panic when one part of the mix isn't going up. That will move your mix away from your goals. That is what periodic re-balancing is supposed to address. It brings you back to your planned mix.

Answer (score 4):

The federal reserve has been raising interest rates for the past half a year, and it is unclear how long it will keep doing so. However, all expectations of future interest rate hikes have already been priced in, both into stock values and bond values.

You are trying to sell an asset which has recently gone down in value (stocks), and buy an asset which has recently gone up in value (bonds). Then, you want to get back into stocks once "the market seems like it's going back up", i.e. once stocks go up relative to bonds. So you not only want to time the market (a bad strategy in itself), your plan is to buy high and sell low both ways. Doesn't sound like a good plan.

As [mhoran_psprep's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/153447/119880) states, you should pick a mix based on your age, goals, and risk tolerance, not chase past peformance.